# I cant't get the latest cookies via middleware or nuxtServerInit in server side in Nuxt2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js, middleware

When a user logs in, I set a token in cookies. I have written a middleware to check whether the user is logged in or not based on the token. However, I have noticed that when the page is first loaded, the cookies I obtain from context.req are not the latest version. Only when I refresh the page, do I get the updated cookies.

So, if I want to obtain the latest cookies on the server-side, what should I do?

I just want to get the latest cookies in server-side.

Comment: Do you set the latest cookies before or after getting the cookies? We need more information, like the code you use to set and get the cookies. Without that, it will be hard to help. So, please edit your question and add the code inside a code block.